# How to create action Listner for a button in another Class

Tags: java, swing

I have a class Abc, which has a button and i have added listner for this buton in  Abc.

```
class Abc
{
Jbutton abuttob=new Jbutton()
abutton.actonListner(this);

 action performed()
{
// on button click goes here
}
}
```

now i have class XYZ.

```
  class XYZ
    {
    Abc oldclass=new Abc();
    oldclass.abutton.addactionlistner();
        action performed(){
   // button click goes here
    }
    }
```

problem is am not able to call action performed nither in Abc class or XYZ class.

Kindly suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 class abc implements ActionListener 
 {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
         {
              System.out.println("This is another class");
         }
  }



   class xyz 
     {
          xyz()
           {
            JButton abuttob = new JButton();
            abuttob.addActionListener(new abc());
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have one of the classes, say, XYZ, implement actionListener().

Then in ABC, add a new XYZ() as the listener to abc's JButton.

There are many alternatives but this is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

You never call event methods, those get called by EventHandlers. Try following code

```
public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               //Implementation
   }
}

public class ButtonDemo {
         public ButtonDemo() {
               ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
               JButton button = new JButton();
               button.addActionListener(buttonListener);
         }
}
```